# Location of Websphere Application Server config files

Tags: eclipse, websphere

I have a Websphere Application Server v8.0, and my job requires me to change the location of my JDBC data source to different values to test in different environments. I traditionally would do this via the admin console and change the settings via the Resources > JDBC > Data sources section, but I'd like to write a script to change these settings. When I run the admin console, where do the settings get stored? I can run the console vis-a-vis the Servers tab in Eclipse (Rational Application Developer) or by navigating to localhost:9044, but I don't know where the settings are stored - which I'd need to write said script.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember of WebSphere Application Server, the settings **are** ultimately persisted to the file system - however you shouldn't be changing them this way because application server config is a messy and complicated business and by directly changing settings you risk destroying your app server.

I'd recommend checking out [this redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247971.html), particularly Chapter 8 which describes how you can configure your app server with scripts. Also I seem to recall plans to display the equivalent scripting commands in the admin console.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I had a quick look locally and found a reference to my JDBC data source in "**resources.xml**" located within the websphere directory at...

```
<server profile root>\config\cells\<aNodeCell>\nodes\<aNode>\servers\<aServer>
```

In the past I've used xml config to read values for convenience, but not often to update. Instead I have made use of some of the jython script options available and can echo Jim's response to check out the options there in case there is something that would be a viable alternative.

Edit:
There is another link that may be of interest [Configuring data access with wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/txml_dataaccess.html). I've not used this particular feature of wsadmin myself but it does appear to show promise at first glance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a script, then rather than looking at file system write a proper jython script, which will do your modifications in the similar way as you would do it via console.

To make writing script easier you can use:

- Command assistance in the console - the Help portlet on the right shows last invoked command in jython
- Script library, which already provides some scripts - [Automating data access resource configuration using wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/txml_7libresource.html?lang=en)
- And basic scripting commands - [Configuring data access with wsadmin scripting](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/txml_dataaccess.html?lang=en)